# Suppress the save alert message while printing an excel document using ShellExecute

Tags: winapi, shellexecute

I'm writing a C++ code with `WINAPI()` and I need to print  many excel documents by using the `ShellExecute()` function as shown below:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"print","c:\\printdocs\\test1.xls",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The above command works fine and prints the Excel document, but the particular excel document is getting opened and an alert message is getting displayed saying 'Do you want to save the changes you made to test1.xls' for every excel document.

Here I don't want the excel sheet to be opened and I need to bypass the alert display so that the all excel documents are printed silently in the background. Please tell me how to print the excel documents silently in the background using `shellExecute()`.

Comment: You cannot do this with `ShellExecute` I expect. You'll need to automate Excel.

Comment: is there any other way to silently print an excel file. please help me with this. im almost at the end of my project but this thing is bugging me alot.

Comment: Try with automation. But doing this through excel possibly not the ideal way to print.

Comment: could u please be more specific about what and where i need to do this automation...

Comment: Do a web search for excel automation